# Server to test UDP port connectivity

Tags: networking, udp

I am looking for a way to test UDP connection, I tried with some VPN servers that I know they have XXX UDP port open, but I didn't know what to send in the body, when I send random strings I don't get any respond

Is there any reliable server that have some UDP port open all time and respond to my connections

Comment: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"

Comment: UDP is not a connection-oriented protocol, it doesn't establish a dedicated end-to-end connection, the information is transmitted in one direction and there is no status verification.

In order to test UDP, you can use a tool called iPerf, there are many tutorials available ([link](http://openmaniak.com/iperf.php)) and it's easy to use. You can either install iperf on another machine or use an online server like the one in the following link:

http://iperf.volia.net/